# Stability of a continuous piecewise linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, stability

I am studying random perturbation of a system that is continuous and piecewise linear. More precisely: I am given a map $\Phi_1:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$$ \Phi_1(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}Ax & \text{if $Cx\ge0$}\\
Bx & \text{otherwise,}\end{array}\right.$$
where $A$, $B$ are $d\times d$ matrices and $C$ is a vector.

I know that $\Phi_1$ is **continuous** (which implies that $A$ and $B$ cannot be too different for example).

I denote by $\Phi_t$ the $t$-th iterations of $\Phi$: $\Phi_t(x) = \Phi(\Phi_{t-1}(x))$. My questions concern the asymptotic properties of the iterations $\Phi_t$:

1. are there "easy" necessary and sufficient conditions that would guarantee that for all $t$: $\lim_{t\to\infty}\Phi_t(x)$=0.
2. if the above property 1. holds, does it hold uniformly for all $x$ such that $\|x\|\le1$?
3. if the above property 2. holds, does it imply that $\Phi_t$ is a contraction for large enough $t$?

---

To add some context, I am considering a noisy version of the iterations above in which $X_{t+1}=\Phi_t(X_t) + \epsilon E_{t+1}$, where $E_{t}$ is a sequence of (bounded) random variables. This implies that $X_{t} = O(\epsilon)$. The property 3. above implies that this holds **uniformly in time** (and I do not know how to prove it otherwise).

Comment: Have you checked results from Daniel Liberzon's book on switched dynamical system?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the link. I do not really know the literature in switching system, I will look into it.